# Onclick for each button inside RecyclerView items

Tags: android, onclicklistener, android-adapter, android-recyclerview

How to get the position for clicked button inside the RecyclerView items

Here's my onBindViewHolder :

```
  public void onBindViewHolder(MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
    Masar masar=masrList.get(position);
    holder.masarName.setText(masar.getMasarTitle());
    holder.masarDesc.setText(masar.getMasarDescreption());

    //How to get the Position 

    holder.masarImg.setImageResource(masar.getMasarImg());

    holder.mapBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v ) {
            //if you need position, just use recycleViewHolder.getAdapterPosition();
            Intent intent = new Intent(v.getContext(), MapsActivity.class);
            mContext.startActivity(intent);
        }
    });

}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you need in **onBindViewHolder** only then you can use

```
holder.getAdapterPosition();
```

and if you need this position clicked in activity and fragment then you have to use callbacks from holder to activity and fragment and have to pass the same getAdapterPosition();

**Edit:** Added sample code for listening position click in fragment/activity

step 1: make an interface or callback

```
public interface RecyclerViewClickListener {

    void onClick(View view, int position);
}
```

step 2: While initializing adapter class in fragment or activity pass the above-created reference as a parameter

```
public YourAdapter(List<SomeModel> modelList, RecyclerViewClickListener listener){
 this.clickListener = listener;
}
```

step 3: In your ViewHolder or similar Class for view initialization do something like this

```
public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {

    private Button mapBtn;

    ViewHolder(View v, RecyclerViewClickListener listener) {
        super(v);
        mapBtn = findViewById(R.id.mapBtn);
        mListener = listener;
        mapBtn.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        mListener.onClick(view, getAdapterPosition());
    }
}
```

you will get the position in your fragment or activity where you have passed the callback reference while initializing the adapter.

Answer (score 2):

Use **holder.getAdapterPosition();**

```
public void onBindViewHolder(final MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
Masar masar=masrList.get(position);
holder.masarName.setText(masar.getMasarTitle());
holder.masarDesc.setText(masar.getMasarDescreption());

//How to get the Position 

holder.masarImg.setImageResource(masar.getMasarImg());

holder.mapBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v ) {
        Toast.makeText(getContext(), "The position is: "+holder.getAdapterPosition(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        Intent intent = new Intent(v.getContext(), MapsActivity.class);
        mContext.startActivity(intent);
    }
});}
```

Comment: Never make position final instead use holder.getAdapterPosition(). Makin position final produces incongruencies. Android Studio even provides a lint with more information.

Comment: You have to give me an extra reputation , because i helped to give new info :p @JoeyDalu